# Right triangle problem

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Find a right triangle such that the hypotenuse minus either side gives a cube.  Use a triangle with sides $x^2 - 4$, $4x$, and $x^2 + 4$

Answer (score 1):

The problem has essentially been solved. The hypotenuse minus the side $x^2-4$ is $8$, a cube.

The hypotenuse minus the other side is $x^2-4x+4$, which is $(x-2)^2$. We want to make this a cube, so we want $x-2$ to be a cube. You can pick $x-2$ to be your favourite (positive) cube.

**Remark:** Note that if $x$ is an integer greater than $2$, then the triangle with sides $x^2-4$, $4x$, and $x^2+4$ really is a Pythagorean triangle, since $(x^2-4)^2+(4x)^2=(x^2+4)^2$.

Comment: im not sure what you mean for me to do with your second comment.... I know the answers are 40, 96, and 104 all multiples of 8 so your first comment makes sense. just trying to connect it all

Comment: The Remark at the end just says that we really do get a Pythagorean triangle. You may not even be expected to check that. So the choices for $x$ are $1^3+2$, $2^3+2$, $3^3+2$, and so on. The smallest triangle of the type being discussed is $(5,2,13)$, the next one is $(96, 40, 104)$.